# Bot Radio Looping Audio discord py discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to play a file over and over again, but I get an error. This is an error :

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_playing'
```

this is my bot discord code :

```
@client.command()
async def p(ctx):
   await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
   channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
   voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

   def repeat(guild, voice, audio):
       voice.play(audio, after=lambda e: repeat(guild, voice, audio))
       voice.is_playing()

   if channel and not voice.is_playing():
       audio = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('audio.mp3')
       voice.play(audio, after=lambda e: repeat(ctx.guild, voice, audio))
       voice.is_playing()
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
@client.command()
async def p(ctx):
   await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
   voice = ctx.voice_client

   if not voice:
       return await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
   
   await voice.connect()

   def repeat(voice, audio):
       voice.play(audio, after=lambda e: repeat(voice, audio))
       voice.is_playing()

   if voice and not voice.is_playing():
       audio = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('audio.mp3')
       voice.play(audio, after=lambda e: repeat(voice, audio))
       voice.is_playing()
```

After looking at your comment, you can make the bot leave and join the voice channel by making a `rejoin` command, which will leave the voice channel and join it again:

```py
@client.command()
async def rejoin(ctx):
    voice = ctx.voice_client
    if not voice:
        return await ctx.send("You're not connected to a voice channel")
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
        await voice.connect()
    else:
        await voice.connect()
```

Comment: It does not give an error, but the bot does not join Voice

Comment: @AbolfazlRabiei You're using your own `join` command, yes?

Comment: I want the bot to both join Voice and play

Comment: @AbolfazlRabiei you didn't mention that in your question statement. Anyway, I've edited my post to add that. Now, it should join the voice channel.

Comment: thanks , What should I do if I want to deafend my bot?

Comment: @AbolfazlRabiei first of all, make sure to mark my answer as correct by clicking the check button. Secondly, to deafen your bot, you do `await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=voice, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)`

Comment: I apologize for asking too much how to get the bot to left voice Channel and rejoin it.

Comment: @AbolfazlRabiei I've edited my code and added a `rejoin` command which will make the bot leave and join the voice channel.

Comment: If you have any more questions, make a new post and ask the question there.